# Dynamically Fill NaN Values in Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a series of numbers. For example:

```
Index Column 1
1      10
2      12
3      24
4      NaN
5      20
6      15
7      NaN
8      NaN
9      2
```

I can't use bfill or ffill as the rule is dynamic, taking the value from the previous row and dividing by the number of consecutive NaN + 1. For example, rows 3 and 4 should be replaced with 12 as 24/2, rows 6, 7 and 8 should be replaced with 5. All other numbers should remain unchanged.

How should I do that?

Note: Edited the dataframe to be more general by inserting a new row between rows 4 and 5 and another row at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
m = (df["Column 1"].notna()) & (
    (df["Column 1"].shift(-1).isna()) | (df["Column 1"].shift().isna())
)
out = df.groupby(m.cumsum()).transform(
    lambda x: x.fillna(0).mean() if x.isna().any() else x
)
```

print(out):

```
   Index  Column 1
0      1      10.0
1      2      12.0
2      3      12.0
3      4      12.0
4      5      20.0
5      6       5.0
6      7       5.0
7      8       5.0
8      9       2.0
```

---

**Explanation and intermediate values:**

Basically look for the rows where the next value is NaN or previous value is NaN but their value itself is not NaN. Those rows form the first row of such groups.

So the `m` in above code looks like:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
```

now I want to form groups of rows that are `['True', <all Falses>]` because those are the groups I want to take average of. For that use `cumsum`

If you want to take a look at those groups, you can use `ngroup()` after `groupby` on `m.cumsum()`:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
```

The above is only to show what are the groups.

Now for each group you can get the mean of the group if the group has any NaN value. This is accomplished by checking for NaNs using `x.isna().any()`.

If the group has any `NaN` value then assign `mean` after filling NaN with 0 ,otherwise just keep the group as is. This is accomplished by the lambda:

```
lambda x: x.fillna(0).mean() if x.isna().any() else x
```

Comment: Apologies as my toy example may not have been general enough. If say there was an additional row between rows 4 and 5 with value 20, that 20 should be retained. Your code will overwrite that 20 to be 12 as well as it is still in the previous group.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)? There is a `method=`s that would probably fitsyour desire

However, if you really want to do as you described above, you can do something like this. (Note that iterating over rows in pandas is considered bad practice, but it does the job)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([10,
12,
24,
np.NaN,
15,
np.NaN,
np.NaN])

for col in df:
  for idx in df.index: # (iterating over rows is considered bad practice)
    local_idx=idx
    while(local_idx+1<len(df) and np.isnan(df.at[local_idx+1,col])):
      local_idx+=1
    if (local_idx-idx)>0:
      fillvalue = df.loc[idx]/(local_idx-idx+1)
      for fillidx in range(idx, local_idx+1):
        df.loc[fillidx] = fillvalue

df
```

Output:

```
    0
0   10.0
1   12.0
2   12.0
3   12.0
4   5.0
5   5.0
6   5.0
```

Comment: I got the following error: method must be one of ['linear', 'time', 'index', 'values', 'nearest', 'zero', 'slinear', 'quadratic', 'cubic', 'barycentric', 'krogh', 'spline', 'polynomial', 'from_derivatives', 'piecewise_polynomial', 'pchip', 'akima', 'cubicspline']. Got 's' instead.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: If you really want to do what you described, i updated my answer with a possible solution