# Pandas fillna bfill ffill based on what another column has in it

Tags: pandas, nan, fillna

```
df['Example'] = df.groupby('Reference')['Example'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

I may be going about this the wrong way. I've been filling nan's in my dataframe for other columns using the above code. Which has worked great for filling missing information. But then I ran across a problem that wouldn't work on to fill a missing value. The situation I have I'm trying to solve now is this. <s>So I want to fill the blanks on the dept fields only on Beta, but I want to fill them with the Dept value from the line whose Description is Outsource. I've seen several conditional fill na examples but not one that works for my situation.</s>  Edited the tables to try and make it less confusing. I wasn't quite expressing properly my issue before. What I'm looking for is if the press field contains beta, then it looks for the line with outsource in it. It uses the dept from outsource to fill the other nans on that invoice that have the same job#. But doesn't fill any other nans.

My dataframe:

| Invoice | Reference | Press | Description | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INV0001 | Job#3045 | Alpha | Copies |  |
| INV0001 | Job#3045 | Alpha | Binding |  |
| INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Design |  |
| INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Outsource | Digital |
| INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Site Survey |  |
| INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Packaging |  |
| INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Mounting Brackets | Sign |
| INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Installation | Sign |
| INV0003 | Job#3067 | Delta | Binding | Bond |
| INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Site Survey |  |
| INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Outsource | Color |
| INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Design |  |
| INV0005 | Job#3058 | Ceta | Installation | Sign |

What I want it to look like after fillna:

| Invoice | Reference | Press | Description | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INV0001 | Job#3045 | Alpha | Copies |  |
| INV0001 | Job#3045 | Alpha | Binding |  |
| INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Design | Digital |
| INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Outsource | Digital |
| INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Site Survey | Digital |
| INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Packaging |  |
| INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Mounting Brackets | Sign |
| INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Installation | Sign |
| INV0003 | Job#3067 | Delta | Binding | Bond |
| INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Site Survey | Color |
| INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Outsource | Color |
| INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Design | Color |
| INV0005 | Job#3058 | Ceta | Installation | Sign |

Comment: There was recently a pretty similar (although not exakt similar) question. May a solution works for your topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74051926/dynamically-fill-nan-values-in-dataframe/74052091?noredirect=1#comment130750315_74052091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you right, this should solve your question. There may is a more efficient way without iterating. But it does the job and should be easy understandable:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
Invoice Reference   Press   Description Dept
INV0001 Job#3045    Alpha   Copies  
INV0001 Job#3045    Alpha   Binding 
INV0002 Job#3055    Beta    Design  
INV0002 Job#3055    Beta    Outsource   Digital
INV0002 Job#3055    Beta    Site Survey 
INV0002 Job#3056    Beta    Packaging   
INV0002 Job#3056    Beta    Mounting Brackets   Sign
INV0002 Job#3056    Beta    Installation    Sign
INV0003 Job#3067    Delta   Binding Bond
INV0004 Job#3042    Beta    Site Survey 
INV0004 Job#3042    Beta    Outsource   Color
INV0004 Job#3042    Beta    Design  
INV0005 Job#3058    Ceta    Installation    Sign
'''), sep="\t")

df.set_index(["Reference", "Press", "Description"], inplace=True)

for (ref, press, descr) in df[df.Dept.isna()].index:
  if press=="Beta" and (ref, press, "Outsource") in df.index:
    df.loc[(ref,press,descr)].Dept = df.loc[(ref, press, "Outsource")].Dept
  else:
    df.loc[(ref,press,descr)].Dept = "" 

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

| index | Invoice | Reference | Press | Description | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | INV0001 | Job#3045 | Alpha | Copies |  |
| 1 | INV0001 | Job#3045 | Alpha | Binding |  |
| 2 | INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Design | Digital |
| 3 | INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Outsource | Digital |
| 4 | INV0002 | Job#3055 | Beta | Site Survey | Digital |
| 5 | INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Packaging |  |
| 6 | INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Mounting Brackets | Sign |
| 7 | INV0002 | Job#3056 | Beta | Installation | Sign |
| 8 | INV0003 | Job#3067 | Delta | Binding | Bond |
| 9 | INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Site Survey | Color |
| 10 | INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Outsource | Color |
| 11 | INV0004 | Job#3042 | Beta | Design | Color |
| 12 | INV0005 | Job#3058 | Ceta | Installation | Sign |

Comment: More info on solution: [Pandas Multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

Comment: Very close to what I'm looking for. Only issue with this, and maybe it's a simple fix, is that it overwrites the description on the rows it fills in the dept on. There doesn't seem to be an easy way around it. I'm reading through the Multiindex page to see if I can discern a fix from that information.

Comment: Ok sort of fixed it, by slicing the column I wanted to write in like this df.loc[(ref,press,descr),4:] = df.loc[(ref, press, "Outsource")], however this produces a warning about this being a type error in a future version. Is there a better way to handle this? In the meantime, I'll keep digging.

Comment: Oh yes thats true! Didn't have seen that. I'll try to update my answer

Comment: @GAT3273  i fixed my soluton. now it should work as you desired

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('Invoice').apply(lambda x:x.ffill().bfill())

    Invoice Press   Description Dept
0   INV0001 Alpha   Something   NaN
1   INV0002 Beta    Something   Digital
2   INV0002 Beta    Outsource   Digital
3   INV0002 Beta    Something   Digital
4   INV0003 Delta   Something   Color
5   INV0004 Beta    Something   Color
6   INV0004 Beta    Outsource   Color
7   INV0004 Beta    Something   Color
8   INV0005 Ceta    Other       Sign
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the requirements correctly, I don't think that works. This would fill an NA value from a non-NA value, even if that value does not correspond to "Department" == "Outsource".

Comment: @NickODell OP question is alittle ambiguous. OP wants to use values from `outsource` yet for `Invoice3` there is no Outsource but still everything has been filled up with `Color`. You see what I mean? Also OP wants to fill Beta values, yet the output shows that everything (not necessarily beta) is filled